# Kernel not updating with atp-get update/upgrade - Ubuntu 21.04 - TFTP boot NFS root

Tags: kernel, update, filesystem, nfs, tftp

I am gradually getting a Pi 4 cluster up and running, and have hit an issue I have not been able to resolve with google. It is my understanding of the Ubuntu boot process that is lacking really.

I have 5 nodes. Each is running Ubuntu 21.04. The first is a storage node, and runs from an SD card. It then has a couple of SSDs in RAID 1 split into 8 partitions. The first 4 partitions contain the root file systems for each of the other 4 nodes and are exported via NFS. Each node has a directory /srv/nfs/{RpiID}>/ where the partition is mounted. This storage node is also running TFTP and has a boot directory for each of the other 4 nodes at /srv/tftpboot/{RpiID}/. These directories are then bind mounted to /srv/nfs/{RpiID}/boot/firmware/ on the storage server.

NFS:

```
mark@rgd-strg-01:~$ ls /srv/nfs/ -la
total 24
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root 4096 Sep 27 14:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Sep 28 12:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Sep 21 08:59 637d46a8
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Sep 21 08:53 68fe97e5
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Sep 21 09:04 727e3e34
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Sep 21 09:11 ba061f16
```

/etc/exports:

```
mark@rgd-strg-01:~$ cat /etc/exports 
/srv/nfs/637d46a8/ *(insecure,rw,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/srv/nfs/68fe97e5/ *(insecure,rw,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/srv/nfs/727e3e34/ *(insecure,rw,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/srv/nfs/ba061f16/ *(insecure,rw,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/srv/tftpboot/ *(insecure,rw,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

TFTP:

```
mark@rgd-strg-01:~$ ls /srv/tftpboot/ -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Sep 28 12:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Sep 28 12:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 28 15:24 637d46a8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 29 09:04 68fe97e5
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 28 13:22 727e3e34
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 28 13:22 ba061f16
```

/etc/fstab:

```
mark@rgd-strg-01:~$ cat /etc/fstab  
LABEL=writable  /        ext4   discard,errors=remount-ro       0 1
LABEL=system-boot       /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults        0       1
/srv/tftpboot/637d46a8 /srv/nfs/637d46a8/boot/firmware  none    defaults,bind 0 0 
/srv/tftpboot/68fe97e5 /srv/nfs/68fe97e5/boot/firmware  none    defaults,bind 0 0
/srv/tftpboot/727e3e34 /srv/nfs/727e3e34/boot/firmware  none    defaults,bind 0 0
/srv/tftpboot/ba061f16 /srv/nfs/ba061f16/boot/firmware  none    defaults,bind 0 0
```

Here is examples of the cmdline.txt and other important files from a node:

cmdline.txt:

```
mark@rgd-strg-01:~$ cat /srv/tftpboot/68fe97e5/cmdline.txt 
net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/nfs 
nfsroot=10.1.0.20:/srv/nfs/68fe97e5,tcp ip=dhcp elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc rw 
cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory
```

fstab:

```
mark@rgd-strg-01:~$ cat /srv/nfs/68fe97e5/etc/fstab 
10.1.0.20:/srv/nfs/68fe97e5   /       nfs     defaults,_netdev   0  0 
tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   defaults    0   0
tmpfs   /var/tmp    tmpfs   defaults    0   0
tmpfs   /var/run    tmpfs   defaults    0   0
```

My issue is that in this configuration (having played with the boot process that I do not fully understand to enable the network booting), everything seems to be working fine, but I am having some trouble with kernel updates on the 4 network nodes. After running apt-get upgrade I get the following message

[image: Message screen shot]

Yet after a reboot, I can see that the kernel has not been updated:

```
mark@rdg-clust-01:~$ uname -r
5.11.0-1007-raspi
```

How can I either correct this properly, or at least do it manually? Can anyone help me understand the boot process a little better? Here is the contents of the boot and firmware directories for a node

Boot:

```
mark@rgd-strg-01:~$ ls /srv/nfs/68fe97e5/boot/ -la
total 133404
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Sep 30 06:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4096 Sep 21 08:53 ..
-rw-------  1 root root  5099714 Jul 28 12:42 System.map-5.11.0- 
1007-raspi
-rw-------  1 root root  5115999 Aug 23 07:05 System.map-5.11.0- 
1017-raspi
-rw-------  1 root root  5115843 Sep 21 14:56 System.map-5.11.0- 
1019-raspi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   233406 Jul 28 12:42 config-5.11.0-1007- 
raspi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   233767 Aug 23 07:05 config-5.11.0-1017- 
raspi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   233790 Sep 21 14:56 config-5.11.0-1019- 
raspi
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       44 Sep 30 06:14 dtb -> dtbs/5.11.0- 
1019-raspi/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       44 Sep 20 16:07 dtb-5.11.0-1007- 
raspi -> dtbs/5.11.0-1007-raspi/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       44 Sep 21 08:56 dtb-5.11.0-1017- 
raspi -> dtbs/5.11.0-1017-raspi/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       44 Sep 30 06:14 dtb-5.11.0-1019- 
raspi -> dtbs/5.11.0-1019-raspi/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root     4096 Sep 30 06:14 dtbs
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Sep 29 09:04 firmware
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Sep 30 06:10 initrd.img -> 
initrd.img-5.11.0-1019-raspi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 28854277 Sep 20 16:07 initrd.img-5.11.0- 
1007-raspi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 31566190 Sep 21 08:56 initrd.img-5.11.0- 
1017-raspi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 31593753 Sep 30 06:14 initrd.img-5.11.0- 
1019-raspi
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Sep 30 06:10 initrd.img.old -> 
initrd.img-5.11.0-1017-raspi
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Sep 30 06:10 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz- 
5.11.0-1019-raspi
-rw-------  1 root root  9464117 Jul 28 12:42 vmlinuz-5.11.0- 
1007-raspi
-rw-------  1 root root  9525235 Aug 23 07:05 vmlinuz-5.11.0- 
1017-raspi
-rw-------  1 root root  9526813 Sep 21 14:56 vmlinuz-5.11.0- 
1019-raspi
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Sep 30 06:10 vmlinuz.old -> 
vmlinuz-5.11.0-1017-raspi
```

Firmware:

```
mark@rgd-strg-01:~$ ls /srv/nfs/68fe97e5/boot/firmware/ -la
total 79968
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Sep 29 09:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Sep 30 06:19 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1024 Sep 16 13:46 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    26914 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    29031 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    28412 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    26910 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    49254 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    48910 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2711-rpi-400.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    49318 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2711-rpi-cm4.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    20140 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2837-rpi-3-a-plus.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    21009 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    20545 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    19872 Sep 16 13:46 bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     4638 Sep 16 13:46 boot.scr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    52456 Sep 16 13:46 bootcode.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      228 Sep 28 13:22 cmdline.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1142 Sep 16 13:46 config.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     7314 Sep 16 13:46 fixup.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     5448 Sep 16 13:46 fixup4.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     3187 Sep 16 13:46 fixup4cd.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     8452 Sep 16 13:46 fixup4db.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     8454 Sep 16 13:46 fixup4x.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     3187 Sep 16 13:46 fixup_cd.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10298 Sep 16 13:46 fixup_db.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10298 Sep 16 13:46 fixup_x.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22666147 Sep 16 13:46 initrd.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1559 Sep 16 13:46 overlay_map.dtb
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    12288 Sep 16 13:46 overlays
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2952960 Sep 16 13:46 start.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2228800 Sep 16 13:46 start4.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   793116 Sep 16 13:46 start4cd.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3722504 Sep 16 13:46 start4db.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2981192 Sep 16 13:46 start4x.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   793116 Sep 16 13:46 start_cd.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4794472 Sep 16 13:46 start_db.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3704808 Sep 16 13:46 start_x.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   515920 Sep 16 13:46 uboot_rpi_3.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   571832 Sep 16 13:46 uboot_rpi_4.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   558216 Sep 16 13:46 uboot_rpi_arm64.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25580032 Sep 16 13:46 vmlinux
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9464117 Sep 16 13:46 vmlinuz
```

From this I can see that vmlinux and vmlinuz in the firmware directory are old, and I presume that these represent the kernel loaded at boot time. So I removed them and created a symbolic link on the node pointing /boot/firmware/vmlinuz to /boot/vmlinuz then I updated /boot/firmware/config.txt and set kernel=vmlinuz. after a reboot it still loads the old kernel. What do I need to do?

Comment: Perhaps [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) would be a better place to ask this question? [For example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592740/how-does-the-ubuntu-boot-process-work)

Comment: Ok I will cross post it. Thank you

Comment: Cross post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367674/kernel-not-updating-with-atp-get-update-upgrade-ubuntu-21-04-tftp-boot-nfs-r

Comment: This is very likely a dupe of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/132676/5538