# Ubuntu: upgraded kernel is not selected in the next boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

My Raspberry Pi 4 was originally loaded with Ubuntu 21.04, but after yesterday's release of 21.10, I upgraded using the `do-release-upgrade` command.

Among the other upgraded packages, there was a new Linux kernel: prior to the upgrade, the kernel version was `5.11.0-1019-raspi`, while a new version `5.13.0-1008-raspi` was installed in the course of the upgrade.

After the requested reboot at the end of the upgrade process, I found out that kernel version `5.11.0-1019-raspi` was still in use. I have attempted to reinstall modules such as `linux-image-5.13.0-1008-raspi`, `linux-image-raspi` `linux-modules-5.13.0-1008-raspi` and `linux-raspi`, as well as removing the old kernel version. I have confirmed that `/boot/vmlinuz` and `/boot/firmware/vmlinuz` point to the same file, and it is the one for version `5.13.0-1008-raspi`. Furthermore, after removing the old version, even `vmlinuz.old` points to the new version, so I have no idea where the system is fetching the old version from. Note that there have been quite a few reboots in the process, even a physical one by removing the power cable.

Regardless of everything done above, the system still boots to `5.11.0-1019-raspi`. I suspect there's a missing installation step that updates some kind of onboard memory on the Raspberry Pi.

Note that, ever since installing Ubuntu 21.04 in this board a few months ago, I've seen `apt upgrade` install new kernel versions -- I am made aware of this due to the need to recompile a custom kernel module. Thus, the upgrade has worked automatically in the past. I'm not sure why it's not working this time.

My question is: what do I need to do make the Raspberry Pi boot the new version of the kernel?

**EDIT**: adding the information requested in the comments:

```
$ mount | grep boot
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot/firmware type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

```
$ ls -R /boot
/boot:
System.map-5.11.0-1019-raspi  config-5.11.0-1019-raspi  config.txt  dtb-5.13.0-1008-raspi  firmware  initrd.img                    initrd.img.old  vmlinuz-5.13.0-1008-raspi
System.map-5.13.0-1008-raspi  config-5.13.0-1008-raspi  dtb         dtbs                   grub      initrd.img-5.13.0-1008-raspi  vmlinuz         vmlinuz.old

/boot/dtbs:
5.11.0-1007-raspi  5.11.0-1019-raspi  5.13.0-1008-raspi

/boot/dtbs/5.11.0-1007-raspi:
bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.bak

/boot/dtbs/5.11.0-1019-raspi:
bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.bak

/boot/dtbs/5.13.0-1008-raspi:
bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb  bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.bak

/boot/firmware:
README                        bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb      bcm2711-rpi-cm4.dtb.bak       bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dtb      config.txt        fixup4db.dat      fixup_db.dat.bak  start.elf         start4db.elf.bak  start_x.elf          uboot_rpi_arm64.bin.bak
bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb           bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb.bak  bcm2837-rpi-3-a-plus.dtb      bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dtb.bak  fixup.dat         fixup4db.dat.bak  fixup_x.dat       start.elf.bak     start4x.elf       start_x.elf.bak      vmlinuz
bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb.bak       bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb      bcm2837-rpi-3-a-plus.dtb.bak  boot.scr                     fixup.dat.bak     fixup4x.dat       fixup_x.dat.bak   start4.elf        start4x.elf.bak   uboot_rpi_3.bin      vmlinuz.bak
bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb      bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.bak  bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb      boot.scr.bak                 fixup4.dat        fixup4x.dat.bak   initrd.img        start4.elf.bak    start_cd.elf      uboot_rpi_3.bin.bak
bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb.bak  bcm2711-rpi-400.dtb      bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb.bak  bootcode.bin                 fixup4.dat.bak    fixup_cd.dat      initrd.img.bak    start4cd.elf      start_cd.elf.bak  uboot_rpi_4.bin
bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb           bcm2711-rpi-400.dtb.bak  bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb           bootcode.bin.bak             fixup4cd.dat      fixup_cd.dat.bak  overlay_map.dtb   start4cd.elf.bak  start_db.elf      uboot_rpi_4.bin.bak
bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb.bak       bcm2711-rpi-cm4.dtb      bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb.bak       cmdline.txt                  fixup4cd.dat.bak  fixup_db.dat      overlays          start4db.elf      start_db.elf.bak  uboot_rpi_arm64.bin
```

Comment: I suggest you ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Cross-posted to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369449/raspberry-pi-4-upgraded-kernel-is-not-selected-in-the-next-boot).

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu do-release-upgrade never worked on the Pi. This tries to upgrade EFI. You needed a different (kluge) to upgrade kernel.

Comment: NOTE Raspberry Pi OS has its own kluge to update files on VFAT partition (which involves copying to ext partition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command fixed it:

```
sudo flash-kernel 5.13.0-1008-raspi
```

I'm pretty sure I saw the same output in the course of my attempts described in the question, but anyway, it's fixed now.